# Array Wont Dump to Sheet? VBA

Tags: arrays, excel, web-scraping, vba

Im having an issue dumping an entire array into a sheet. Is it b/c its not defined as variant?

```
Sub pix()
    Dim htm As Object
    Dim Tr As Object
    Dim Td As Object
    Dim Tab1 As Object
    Dim tblArr(500) As String
    Dim this$
    Dim counter#

    Web_URL = "pathtosite"
    Set HTML_Content = CreateObject("htmlfile")

    With CreateObject("msxml2.xmlhttp")
        .Open "GET", Web_URL, False
        .send
        HTML_Content.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With
    counter = 0

    For Each Tab1 In HTML_Content.getElementsByTagName("div")
        If Tab1.className = "resizing-cig" Then
            this = Tab1.innerText
            tblArr(counter) = this
        End If
        counter = counter + 1
    Next Tab1

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:A500").Value2 = tblArr 'This line

End Sub
```

Comment: You need to define it as a 2D array - `Dim tblArr(1 To 500, 1 To 1)` and load it like `tblArr(counter, 1) = ...` and initialise `counter = 1`

Comment: @chrisneilsen Well just as i thought how much of an idiot i was by forgetting that WS objects are 2d arrays, it turns out that this isnt working either.

Comment: "not working" isn't much to go on...

Comment: @chrisneilsen  I know - I am in the middle of trying some more troubleshooting to see if its user error.

Comment: I just ran your code (with my mods) and it _does_ write some stuff to the sheet.  So the general approach works, I can't tell if it's the _right_ stuff

Comment: @chrisneilsen hence why im checking for user error LOL Ive noticed some interesting stuff going so im investigating things. It might be some weird interactions with html elements and arrays.

Comment: @chrisneilsen so I have noticed that the line in quesiton does dump to sheet, but for some reason, adds 29 extra blank rows. Which is weird. Ill attempt to trouble shoot this later. Thanks for your time :)

Comment: probably all you need to do is move the `counter = counter + 1` inside the `If` block.  Also you could make the size dynamic (you are currently assuming a max of 500 results)

Comment: @chrisneilsen yeah I figured that out after I was reviewing code going "WTF".... so yeah def a user error. Man im an idiot lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Collecting the issues from comments

1. place 2D array onto sheet
2. use dynamic array size
3. increment counter only when new data point is found
4. optional: clear old data
5. declare *all* variables - you should use `Option Explicit`
6. account for possibility of no results

---

```
Sub pix()
    Dim htm As Object
    Dim Tr As Object
    Dim Td As Object
    Dim Tab1 As Object
    Dim tblArr() As String
    Dim this$
    Dim counter#
    Dim Web_URL$
    Dim HTML_Content As Object

    ' Clear old data
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
        .Range(.Cells(1, 1), Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)).ClearContents
    End With

    Web_URL = "http://magic.wizards.com/en/articles/archive/card-image-gallery/eternal-masters"
    Set HTML_Content = CreateObject("htmlfile")

    With CreateObject("msxml2.xmlhttp")
        .Open "GET", Web_URL, False
        .send
        HTML_Content.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With

    ReDim tblArr(1 To 500) As String
    counter = 1

    For Each Tab1 In HTML_Content.getElementsByTagName("div")
        If Tab1.className = "resizing-cig" Then
            this = Tab1.innerText
            tblArr(counter) = this
            counter = counter + 1

            ' Increase array size if full
            If counter > UBound(tblArr) Then
                ReDim Preserve tblArr(1 To UBound(tblArr) + 500)
            End If
        End If
    Next Tab1

    ' resize result array to actual results
    If counter > 1 Then
        ReDim Preserve tblArr(1 To counter - 1)
        ' Transpose to 2D array
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").Resize(UBound(tblArr), 1).Value2 = Application.Transpose(tblArr)
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi to dump the values its best to use a foreach loop

```
j=0
for each element in tblArr

   if element <> "" then

     ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:A500").offset(j,0).Value2 = element 
     j=j+1

   end if
next element
```

Hope this helps you :).

Comment: As much as i appreciate your input, this is not an efficient way to do this. Writing directly to a sheet more than once is the worst and my finished output when i am done with this project with be 1k+ lines. My method above works its just i had some user errors going on

Comment: Ok fair, point. I will check the efficiency of what you are proposing. 
Maybe I did not help you but at least I learned something ;).

Comment: keep in mind if you use my method youll need to adjust for range vs array size. Things get weird on the output if there's a variance (im sure youll notice when playing around with it)